# Drag and drop error and unable to flip item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I have problem when i will transfer all items to one group, next I can't move them to another one because I throw a bug : Unable to find draggable with id: X

example drag and drop located here : https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-johnson-ky04r?file=/src/Table.js